# How to round CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, cgfloat

I made this method

```
+ (CGFloat) round: (CGFloat)f {
    int a = f;
    CGFloat b = a;
    return b;
}
```

It works as expected but it only rounds down. And if it's a negative number it still rounds down.

This was just a quick method I made, it isn't very important that it rounds correctly, I just made it to round the camera's x and y values for my game.

Is this method okay? Is it fast? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are already standard functions with behaviors you might need in `<math.h>` such as: `floorf`, `ceilf`, 
`roundf`, `rintf` and `nearbyintf` (lasf 'f' means "float" version, versions without it are "double" versions).

It is better to use standard methods not only because they are standard, but because they work better in edge cases.

**2013 Update (jessedc)**

iOS is no longer only 32 bit. There are a number of other answers to this question that are now more relevant.

Most answers mention importing `tgmath.h`

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352779/184130
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695011/184130

Comment: Ah, thank you,

Assuming the iPhone is 32-bit it'd be best to use those float functions. :D

Comment: Anyone knows a macro to allow coding for 32-bit and 64-bit CPUs?

Comment: Just create your own macro, see my comment somewhere else in this page

Answer (score 71):

## 2018 Answer

The other answers here are either dated or don't give good examples. It is easy to round a `CGFloat` using Swift's built in `rounded` function.

```
let x: CGFloat = 3.5
let y = x.rounded() // 4.0
```

If you want to round the value in place you can use `round`:

```
var x: CGFloat = 3.5
x.round() // 4.0
```

## Rounding Rules

If you want more precise control over how numbers are rounded, you can use a [`FloatingPointRoundingRule`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule).

#### [Away from zero](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2297782-awayfromzero)

```
x.rounded(.awayFromZero)
```

Numbers above zero are rounded up and numbers below zero are rounded down.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  4.0
3.499  ->  4.0
3.500  ->  4.0
3.999  ->  4.0

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -4.0
-3.499  ->  -4.0
-3.500  ->  -4.0
-3.999  ->  -4.0
```

#### [Down](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2295710-down)

```
x.rounded(.down)
```

Rounds any number with a decimal value down to the next smaller whole number. This is the same as `floor(x)`.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  3.0
3.499  ->  3.0
3.500  ->  3.0
3.999  ->  3.0

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -4.0
-3.499  ->  -4.0
-3.500  ->  -4.0
-3.999  ->  -4.0
```

#### [To nearest or away from zero](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2297294-tonearestorawayfromzero)

```
x.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)   // same as x.rounded()
```

Decimal numbers get rounded to the nearest integer value. However, when the value is exactly in the middle (like `3.5` or `-3.5`) then positive numbers get rounded up and negative numbers get rounded down.

It may have a long complicated name, but this is normally how one learns rounding in school. It is also the rule used if you just do `x.rounded()`.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  3.0
3.499  ->  3.0
3.500  ->  4.0  ***
3.999  ->  4.0

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -3.0
-3.499  ->  -3.0
-3.500  ->  -4.0  ***
-3.999  ->  -4.0
```

#### [To nearest or even](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2299455-tonearestoreven)

```
x.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)
```

This is similar to `toNearestOrAwayFromZero`, except now the `.5` values get rounded to the even whole number.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  3.0
3.499  ->  3.0
3.500  ->  4.0   ***
3.999  ->  4.0
4.500  ->  4.0   ***

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -3.0
-3.499  ->  -3.0
-3.500  ->  -4.0   ***
-3.999  ->  -4.0
-4.500  ->  -4.0   ***
```

#### [Toward zero](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2297208-towardzero)

```
x.rounded(.towardZero)
```

This just has the effect of cutting off any decimal values. If you needed an `Int` you could do the same thing with `Int(x)`.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  3.0
3.499  ->  3.0
3.500  ->  3.0
3.999  ->  3.0

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -3.0
-3.499  ->  -3.0
-3.500  ->  -3.0
-3.999  ->  -3.0
```

#### [Up](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/2299070-up)

```
x.rounded(.up)
```

This is the opposite of `.down`. All decimal numbers are rounded up. This is the same as `ceil(x)`.

```
3.000  ->  3.0
3.001  ->  4.0
3.499  ->  4.0
3.500  ->  4.0
3.999  ->  4.0

-3.000  ->  -3.0
-3.001  ->  -3.0
-3.499  ->  -3.0
-3.500  ->  -3.0
-3.999  ->  -3.0
```

## Notes

- Don't forget to take negative values into account.
- The results of `round` and `rounded` are still `CGFloat`. If you need an `Int` you have to convert it like `Int(myCGFloat)`.
- There is no need to use the C math functions `round(x)`, `ceil(x)` and `floor(x)` anymore. However, if you do use them, they handle both 64 and 32 bit architecture so any answers you may have seen with `roundf`, `ceilf` and `floorf` are now obsolete.

Comment: Great example of a great answer on SO. Thank you.

Comment: This would be a great answer, except for the fact that the question is tagged `objective-c` ...

Answer (score 5):

A `CGFloat` is typedef'd to either a `double` or a `float`, so you can round them like any other real type:

```
CGFloat round(CGFloat aFloat)
{
    return (int)(aFloat + 0.5);
}
```

Note that while this works with floats small enough to carry a fraction, it may act weird on large values.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel - and this is a C question, not Objective C.  Just use the standard C round() function.

Comment: I am curious why this got two downvotes on the same day - especially as it is an exactly correct answer, just not as expansive as the accepted one.

Comment: Well `round()` is for `doubles` and `roundf()` is for `floats`. `CGFloat` is on 32-bit systems a `float` and on 64-bit systems a `double`

Comment: Still doesn't explain the down votes - remember that this was three years ago!

Comment: Might be due to the theoretical possibility of a CGFloat being redefined to double

Answer (score 1):

Try `#import "tgmath.h"`.

The `<tgmath.h>` header will include the headers `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` and will define several type-generic macros.

Answer (score 0):

For working with 32 and 64 bit you can create your own macro's like

```
#ifndef CGFLOAT_CEIL
    #ifdef CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
        #define CGFLOAT_CEIL(value) ceil(value)
    #else
        #define CGFLOAT_CEIL(value) ceilf(value)
    #endif
#endif
```

Ps this isn't an answer for the question but an addition for the question about how to work with 32/64 bit values.

Define this in a file like MyMacros.h and than add an import in the myapp-Prefix.pch

Also remember that choosing CGFloat as prefix for your function can be a risk since apple might add a macro like this them self so that is why the #ifndef CGFLOAT_CEIL is

Comment: I wouldn't re-invent the wheel here. tgmath.h ("type generic" math), as mentioned in other answers, already provides good macros for dealing with architecturally-different types.

Comment: This is just an example that can be applied for multiple solutions. Perhaps you do not agree on this example but can you tell me how NSUserDefaults i.e. can store an CGFloat? It has functions to set an float or double. Just like NSNumber does not have an function to retrieve an CGFloat. There are a lot of ways that this might be useful. And of course i do agree that you should not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: tgmath is overkill when all most people need is the right variant of round/floor/ceil. I also don't like that it redefines the standard functions, rather then using new names. I prefer this simple macro approach.