# iOS warning message : Incompatible pointer types passing 'CGFloat *' (aka 'double *') to parameter of type 'float *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is causing my App to act up. this error is happening on this line `modff(floatIndex, &intIndex);` What do I need to do to fix this issue?

Edit: it is because of &intIndex

```
- (BOOL)isFloatIndexBetween:(CGFloat)floatIndex {
  CGFloat intIndex, restIndex;
  restIndex = modff(floatIndex, &intIndex);
   BOOL isBetween = fabsf(restIndex - 0.5f) < EPSILON;
  return isBetween;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

As I recall CGFloat is defined as float on 32 bit devices and double on 64 bit devices. Thus you don't want to use CGFloat in a call to modff(). Instead, declare your parameters using a specific type, and use casting.

Something like this (In this case I am using modf and all float variables.

```
- (BOOL)isFloatIndexBetween:(CGFloat)floatIndex 
{
  float restIndex;
  float first, second;
  first = (float) floatIndex; 
  restIndex = modf(first, &second);
  BOOL isBetween = fabsf(restIndex - 0.5f) < EPSILON;
  return isBetween;
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, [importing `tgmath.h`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7695011/1445366) will give you access to some functions that let you handle this differently. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5352779/1445366).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `CGFloat`s (typedef'ed to `double` on your system) to functions that expect `float`s.

You can either change `modff` and `fabsf` to `modf` and `fabs`, respectively (slower but more precise), or change `intIndex` and `restIndex` to be `float`s instead of `double`s (faster but less precise).

Answer (score 1):

Learning to speak compiler error/warning is an invaluable skill. In this case, it is telling you that `modff` is expecting a `float` (that is, a single-precision floating point number), but you're passing it a `CGFloat` (which is typedef'd as a `double`, which is a double-precision floating point number). As NobodyNada says, you can either change which function you're using or the type if `intIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to avoid these types of warnings and errors when using an architecture specific types like `CGFloat` is to put `#import <tgmath.h>` in your precompiled header or the imports for this file. That way the type-generic versions of the underly C functions are used. In this case it makes your warnings go away without any code changes. Then it's just a matter of making sure the precision is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64-bit architectures (like arm64),then you should use CGFloat because it is defined as double and therefore a 8-byte floating point number, whereas float is a 4-byte floating point number.

So you should use these according to architecture.

Comment: Yes we can use CGFloat instead of float.