# Replacement for `fabs`, `fmax`, etc. for use with CGFloat on 64-bit iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgfloat

### Question

Consider layout code like this:

```
CGFloat descriptionHeight = // height of a paragraph of text with zero or more words;
CGFloat imageHeight = // height of an image;
CGFloat yCoordinateOfSomeOtherView = fmax(descriptionHeight, imageHeight) + 5.0f;
```

How should the third line be rewritten with support for 64-bit iOS devices?

(The current code doesn't take into account whether `yCoordinateOfSomeOtherView` is a `float` or a `double`.)

### Options

A few options (I'm not sure which is best):

#### 1. Define my own macro

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
#define cgfmax(x,y) fmaxf(x,y)
#else
#define cgfmax(x,y) fmax(x,y)
#endif
```

I could then replace `fmax` with `cgfmax`.

#### 2. Use `tgmath.h`

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352779/1445366) from 2011 suggests replacing `math.h` with `tgmath.h`.  This replaces the implementation of `fmax` with one that calls `__typeof__` on each argument and returns either `fmax` or `fmaxf` depending on the argument types.

#### 3. Ignore this issue

Since CGFloats relate to layout, the data loss potentially incurred storing a `float` into a `double` will usually be insignificant.  That is, they'll represent tiny fractions of pixels.

### Summary

I'm looking for any other options or helpful advice from someone who's done a 32-bit to 64-bit transition before.

Comment: Yeah, layout stuff doesn't really hit the 32-bit limit. So it probably won't be a problem, but its fun to do the mental exercise for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is never any "data loss" incurred when converting a `float` into a `double`.  That conversion is always exact.

Your solutions 1 & 2 are entirely equivalent semantically, though (2) is more stylistically correct.

Your solution 3 is formally not equivalent; it may incur extra conversions between float and double, which may make it slightly less efficient (but the actual result is identical).

Basically, it doesn't matter, but use `tgmath`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other way around.  (By "data loss", I mean the truncation of 64-bit values when they are assigned to a 32-bit type.)  That is, two `double`s would go into `fmax`, and a `float` would come out.

Comment: @AaronBrager: Sure, but in your case you know that the arguments to `fmax` were originally `CGFloat`s, which means that their maximum (the return value) is exactly representable as a `CGFloat`, so there can be no rounding.  The result is still exact.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't worry about it (I'd personally just use `fmax`, etc.) unless you measure a real performance issue.

Comment: @StephenCanon To clarify I understand you correctly: the result is still exact because the implementation of `fmax` doesn't assign anything; it just returns one of its two arguments.  But if the implementation of `fmax` assigned the value to a new `float` and then returned this variable, there could be truncation.  Is that correct?

Comment: @AaronBrager no truncation occurs because the value of the result is guaranteed to be exactly representable as a CGFloat.  Assignment doesn't play into it.