# iOS: using vDSP functions in 64bit

Tags: ios, floating-point, 32bit-64bit, accelerate-framework, vdsp

In iOS, I have a function call that depends on [vDSP_vgathr](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vgathr), a member of Apple's [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html):

```
int pix = image.size.height * image.size.width;
float * array = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * pix * 4);
float * colorPlane = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * pix);
float * y_r = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * pix)
int * malloc(sizeof(int) * pix)

vDSP_vgathr(colorPlane, (const vDSP_Length *)idx, 1, y_r, 1, (int)(rate*pix));
```

I've seen [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651788/whats-the-meaning-of-exception-code-exc-i386-gpflt) that relating to the error I get, `EXC_I386_GPFLT`, and 64 bit systems and non-canonical pointers. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352457/cgfloat-based-math-functions/5352779#5352779) (and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506238/replacement-for-fabs-fmax-etc-for-use-with-cgfloat-on-64-bit-ios-devices)) I've seen suggest including `tgmath.h`, but when used (with a successful compile), it does nothing and I still get `EXC_I386_GPFLT`.

I've tried a host of other potential solutions including typecasting various objects and different function calls. How can I do I make this function call work with the 64 bit architecture?

Comment: `tgmath` does absolutely nothing relating in any way to the problem you’re having.  There’s not enough information to go on in your code sample to tell what’s going on; can you provide an actual compile-able version of your code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for `vDSP_vgathr` say it's defined as

```
void vDSP_vgathr (
   float *__vDSP_A,
   vDSP_Length *__vDSP_B,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_J,
   float *__vDSP_C,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_K,
   vDSP_Length __vDSP_N
);
```

You're passing an int into that function and `vDSP_Length` is defined as `unsigned long.` So, pass an unsigned long in:

```
unsigned long * idxSend = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * N);
for (i=0; i<N; i++) idxSend[i] = (unsigned long)idx[i];
vDSP_vgathr(..., idxSend, ...);
```

That solves your problem.