# tgmath.h doesn't work if modules are enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, llvm-clang

I looked into using `tgmath.h` to deal with the `CGFloat typedef float/double` mess when dealing with arm64.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267237/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-use-tgmath-on-ios) has a pretty good description of how to use it, except that it didn't work at all for me. No matter what, my code was still calling the `math.h` functions.

After spending some time looking at all of the project compiler settings, I found that disabling the "Modules" feature ([@import vs #import - iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7)) makes it all work. More specifically, the option in the project settings is called `Enable Modules(C and Objective-C)` in the `Apple LLVM 5.1 - Language - Modules` dropdown.

To see a quick example of this issue, download a project that uses tgmath, [such as MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), and see what happens when you enable the modules project setting. The `tgmath.h` calls get replaced with regular `math.h` calls.

My question is:

1. Why do modules prevent tgmath from being imported properly?
2. Is there a way to get around it and use both tgmath and modules? I would like to still be able to use them.

Comment: That looks like a compiler bug to me, and you should report it at bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Yes, please do, and please let us know the bug number.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks guys. I submitted a radar issue and also posted it on openradar. Here is the openradar link: http://www.openradar.me/16744288

Comment: A dirty fix for the time being is copy the #undef and #define macro pairs for each thmath function, right after importing thmath.h. I do this in my .pch file to have those helpers accessible throughout the app.

Comment: Thank you; an engineer has been investigating the underlying issue, but I’m afraid I can’t give a timeframe for a fix.

Comment: @MatejBukovinski, thanks for the idea. I was considering doing that too, but ultimately decided to just go with the path of least resistance and turn off modules until this is fixed. Also: great work on MBProgressHUD, I use it all the time :)

Comment: For anyone following this, my bug was closed as a duplicate of another bug 14459641, so I guess at least someone has reported this before.

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/15638008 this one

Comment: Mine was closed as a duplicate of 14459641 as well.

Comment: I wrote an alternative to tgmath that uses Clang's overloadable attribute: https://github.com/simonwhitaker/swmath

Comment: @SimonWhitaker nice addition but it's worth noting that this is pretty much exactly how tgmath works also. The code is almost identical.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but as a workaround you could at least disable modules for only the file(s) where you're using `tgmath.h`:

- Navigate to the target's Build Phases tab in Xcode.
- Under the Compile Sources phase, locate the source files.
- Double-click the source file and type `-fno-modules` in the Compiler Flags popover to disable Clang modules for that file.

At least this way you would still get the benefits of modules in most of your project. (This is assuming, of course, you don't need `tgmath.h` in the majority of your source files.)

Comment: Thanks for contributing, unfortunately this is a kind of time consuming solution in a project with hundreds of files.

Answer (score 1):

It might already be in your math library under the name ctgmath: [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctgmath)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case.