# CGFloat floor to NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In Xcode, the compiler is complaining about the following cast:

`CGFloat width = 5.6f;
 NSInteger num = (NSInteger)floor(width);`

Saying "**cast from function call of type 'double' to non-matching type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')**"

One workaround would be to simply cast the CGFloat to NSInteger which truncates but I want to make the code clear/easy to read by explicitly flooring. Is there a function for flooring that returns an int? Or some other (clean) way of doing this?

My compiler settings under "Apple LLVM 6.0 - Compiler Flags", in "Other C Flags", I have **-O0 -DOS_IOS -DDEBUG=1 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wnewline-eof -Wconversion -Wendif-labels -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wenum-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated**

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code and it works perfectly fine without any errors. Did you try compiling it again? This can sometimes help.

Comment: I think this may have to do with compiler settings--mine are on a fairly strict setting (and must stay that way).

Comment: i tried the code you specified and there were no errors.  What settings do you have?

Comment: In "Apple LLVM 6.0 - Custom Compiler Flags" in my Build Settings I have: **-O0 -DOS_IOS -DDEBUG=1 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wnewline-eof -Wconversion -Wendif-labels -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wenum-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, as you mentioned strict compiler settings, I tried again and found the solution.
The compiler warning is because you are trying to cast the floor function to a NSInteger value and not the returned value.
To solve this, all you have to do, is to put floor(width) in parentheses like this:

```
NSInteger num = (NSInteger) (floor(width));
```

or save the result of the floor operation to another CGFloat and cast the new variable to NSInteger

```
CGFloat floored = floor(width);
NSInteger num = (NSInteger) floored;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `floorf()` for floats. So `NSInteger num = (NSInteger)floorf(width);`

More information [CGFloat-based math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5352457/4114683)

Comment: floorf returns a float, I get the same error:
 "cast from function call of type 'float' to non-matching type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')"

Comment: Weird. In C, it is perfectly legal to cast a `float` into an `int`... or isn't it?

Comment: This is because of my compiler settings--I can't cast a method's return value to another type directly.