# How to safely floor or ceil a CGFloat to int?

Tags: ios, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I often need to floor or ceil a `CGFloat` to an `int`, for calculation of an array index.

The problem I permanently see with `floorf(theCGFloat)` or `ceilf(theCGFloat)` is that there can be troubles with floating point inaccuracies.

So what if my `CGFloat` is `2.0f` but internally it is represented as `1.999999999999f` or something like that. I do `floorf` and get `1.0f`, which is a float again. And yet I must cast this beast to int which may introduce another problem.

Is there a best practice how to floor or ceil a `float` to an `int` such that something like `2.0` would never accidentally get floored to `1` and something like `2.0` would never accidentally get ceiled to `2`?

Comment: This question cannot be answered correctly until specifications are provided describing the error in the input value and what the consequences are of returning values that are too high or too low. There are trade-offs between returning a value that is too high because previous rounding-error made the value too high and returning a value that is too low because the value was artificially adjusted to compensate for the preceding error, and vice-versa. Without explanation of context, there is no single correct answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple misconceptions in your question.

> > what if my CGFloat is 2.0f but internally it is represented as 1.999999999999f

can't happen; 2.0, like all reasonably small integers, has an exact representation in floating-point.  If your `CGFloat` is `2.0f`, then it really is 2.0.

> > something like 2.0 would never accidentally get ceiled to 2

The ceiling of 2.0 *is* 2; what else would it possibly be?

---

I think the question that you're really asking is "suppose I do a calculation that produces an inexact result, which mathematically *should* be exactly 2.0, but is actually slightly less; when I apply `floor` to that value, I get 1.0 instead of 2.0--how do I prevent this?"

That's actually a fairly subtle question that doesn't have a single "right" answer.  How have you computed the input value?  What are you going to do with the result?

Answer (score 34):

**Swift supplemental answer**

I am adding this as a supplemental answer for those who come here looking how to use `floor` and `ceil` with a `CGFloat` (like I did).

```
var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
floor(myCGFloat) // 3.0
ceil(myCGFloat) // 4.0
```

And if an `Int` is needed, then it can be cast to one.

```
var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
Int(floor(myCGFloat)) // 3
Int(ceil(myCGFloat)) // 4
```

**Update**

There is no need to use the C `floor` and `ceil` functions anymore. You can use the Swift `round()` with [rounding rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785079/3681880).

```
var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
myCGFloat.round(.down) // 3.0
myCGFloat.round(.up) // 4.0
```

If you don't wish to modify the original variables, then use `rounded()`.

**Notes**

- Works with both 32 and 64 bit architectures.

**See also**

- [How to round CGFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785079/3681880)

Answer (score 4):

EDIT - read the comments for reasons why this answer isn't right :)

Casting a `float` to an `int` is an implicit `floorf` i.e. `(int)5.9` is `5`. If you don't mind that then just cast :)

If you want to round up then just cast the result of a `ceilf` - casting after rounding shouldn't introduce any errors at all (or, if you want, add one before casting i.e. `(int)(5.9+1)' is '6' - same as rounding up).

To round to the nearest, just add 0.5 - `(int)(5.9+0.5)` is `6` but `(int)(5.4+0.5)` is `5`. Though I would just use `roundf(5.9)` :)

Comment: Casting float to int is not an implicit floor. It is, in C and some other common languages, a truncation (toward zero). Floor is rounding to the nearest integer in the direction of negative infinity. Converting -3.5 to integer yields -3, but floor(-3.5) is -4.

Comment: OK, that's a fair point - I'd oversimplified to the point of just being wrong :)