# UIPageControl set numberOfPages with UICollectionView page?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to add an `UIPageControl` and `UICollectionView`. My collection is enable paging, and now I want my page control `numberOfPages` is the collection view number of page.

I try to set it like this:

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.gridMenuCollection.frame.size.width / self.gridMenuCollection.contentSize.width;
```

but it's not work. If using my data array for `numberOfPage` it return alot of dots and I don't want to do it.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the devision the other way around.
Should be:

`self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.gridMenuCollection.contentSize.width / self.gridMenuCollection.frame.size.width;`

And also use `ceiling` to show the correct amount of dots. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993981/how-to-safely-floor-or-ceil-a-cgfloat-to-int)
e.g. 
content width is 1200
frame width is 500
content / frame = 2.4
ceil(content / frame) = 3

And you want to show 3 dots, because the elements will fit only to 3.

Comment: I tried your solution but the number of pages is nil. I think it's cannot get the contentSize.width & collectionview width because I'm put an breakpoint on it and then print out both `self.gridMenuCollection.contentSize.width` & `self.gridMenuCollection.frame.size.width` then console say: `error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double')`. Using `ceiling` got the same issue.

Comment: Oh wait. It's work, but the dots doesn't show up instantly. I put my collection into a UIView as a popup, the first time I show this popup the dots not appear. It's only show up after I dismiss the popup then show popup again.

Comment: Fixed by put it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` It's show instantly.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the answer.