# numberOfRowsInSection / 3 - Only returning 15 images and not 16 or 17 as they're not divisible by 3

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I am querying images from parse to display in my tableViewCell which has 3 imageView inside of it. So If I have 15 images I will get 5 TableView rows and all the images will display correctly.

But if I have 16 or 17 image, which aren't a multiple of 3 the images are not shown, which is quite logical as i have add my query count divided by 3. But I have been recomended a method by another very helpful user on here @Wottle that should fix this issue, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly! Here is my code below, I hope someone is able to help me!

And I am grateful for your time.

this function should allow me to visualize the images even if they'r enot a multiple of 3.

```
 func roundUp(value: Double) -> Int {
        if value == Double(Int(value)) {
            return Int(value)
        } else if value < 0 {
            return Int(value)
        } else {
            return Int(value) + 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return roundUp( Double(imageArray.count / 3) )



    }
```

And here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
        var counter = (indexPath.row * 3)

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ProfileTableViewCell


        for imageView in cell.threeImages {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder")

            if counter < imageArray.count {
            let finalImage = imageArray[counter++]["image"]
            finalImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        imageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)

                    }}}}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Just out for curiosity... why not using UICollectionView? In this case it's easier to use and more flexible to layout.

Comment: @NicolaGiancecchi yes I know but in this case I cannot, it's to do with the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageArray.count` and `3` are both integers, so dividing them will give you an integer.  It's too late to try to convert that integer to a double after the calculation is already done, you have to convert them to doubles and do the division on the doubles.

Change it to `return roundUp(Double(imageArray.count) / 3.0)`

Comment: Quick question, I'll post another question if you can help! Is there a way to disable those one or two extra imageView that appear?

Comment: You could add an else block to your `if counter < imageArray.count {` and hide the image view or set their image to nil.

Comment: Because it only works with a placeholder, I'll give that a go

Comment: Doesn't seem to hide the placeholder!

Comment: Hiding the image view would definitely hide the placeholder.  Probably better to post a new question with the updated code than to try to debug it in these comments.

Comment: Will do that, I'll link it.. I dont think I can post for a while now!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would avoid that nasty `roundUp` function altogether. You don't have to use decimal numbers for a simple calculations like this.

The following will do the trick:

```
return (imageArray.count + 2) / 3
```

(`2` being the divisor `3` minus one).

Comment: That definitely works, but as I already marked the other guys correct it's not really fair if I change it..! but thanks alot anyway, I am also trying to figure out how to hide that extra placeholder/imageView that display..And if I don't figure it out in the next couple of hours or so I'll probably be asking another question! I'll send you a link I'd love your help if possible..

Comment: Actually after writing that comment I had an idea and it worked! Thanks alot again for your interest and tip!