# Swift 3 - round-up double of for-loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift3, range

I'm looking for an **Swift 3 Equivalence** for this C-style for-loop:

```
double upperBound = 12.3
for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; ++i) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
var upperBound = 12.3
for i in 0..<Int(upperBound) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

A dynamic `upperBound` ruins the naive approach. The code above won't work for `upperBound = 12.3`, since `Int(12.3) = 12`. `i` would loop through `[0, ..., 11]` (*12 excluded*). `i in 0...Int(upperBound)` won't work for `upperBound = 12.0`, since `Int(12.0) = 12`. `i` would loop through `[0, ..., 12]` (*12 included*).

What is the **Swift 3** way of handling situations like this?

Comment: Is there a ceiling() function you could call? EDIT - Does this answer do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24182426/1061011

Comment: I'm confused as to what your goal is... what do you want the last number you loop through to be?

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure what results you're trying to achieve, either.

Comment: See [Swift 3 for loop with increment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37170203/2976878) – you can use `stride(from:to:by:)`.

Comment: Yes, if you're rewriting a .c file in Swift 3, why don't you just set var upperBound = 11 since that's all it seems you need.

Comment: @Bawpotter I wan't to loop up to the greatest integer smaller than `upperBound` (e.g. _12_ for `upperBound = 12.3` and _11_ for `upperBound = 12.0`).

Comment: @DanielLegler In the real code `upperBound` is dynamic.

Comment: From what I understand, it sounds like he wants 12 included in the loop. Looking at this question again, C would loop from [0, 12) like this Swift code with the boundary condition he's testing. All that needs to be done to include 12 would be replacing '<' with '<='.

Comment: @Chris So `for i in 0..<ceil(upperBound)`. This seems like a good idea..

Comment: Cool. Disregard my most recent comment then, I didn't see your reply to Bawpotter when I was writing it.

Comment: @Chris You code `ceil(upperBound)` approach does exactly what I want. Thank you. If you write it as an answer I would be more than happy to accept it :)

Comment: @Hamish: Only that `stride(from: 0.0, to: upperBound, by: 1.0)` makes the loop variable a `Double` and you have to convert each value to `Int`. But it is a possible solution of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Credit to Martin R for this more Swift-y answer:**

You can make use of the FloatingPoint protocol, whose behavior is [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488326/1061011), to always round up:
`upperBound.rounded(.up)`

**Original Answer:**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181992/round-up-a-cgfloat-in-swift), using `ceil(upperBound)` will cause any value greater than (in your example) 12 to be rounded up to 13.

Comment: Or `upperBound.rounded(.up)`

Comment: I like that even more, do you want to make a new answer or should I just edit mine?

Comment: No need for a separate answer, feel free to edit yours.