# Rounding in Swift with round()

Tags: swift, xcode6, rounding

While playing around, I found the round() function in swift. It can be used as below:

```
round(0.8)
```

Which will return 1, as expected. Here's my question:

**how do I round by thousandths  in swift?**

I want to be able to plug in a number, say 0.6849, and get 0.685 back. How does round() do this? Or, does it not, in which case, what function does?

Comment: `round(1000 * x) / 1000`

Comment: In the simplest case, use `round(x * 1000) / 1000`. Also see [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036978/1966109) to find other ways to round a double using `NSDecimalNumber`, `NSNumberFormatter`, `String initializer`, etc.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can do:

```
round(1000 * x) / 1000
```

Comment: Updated for SWIFT 3 : `someval.rounded()`

Answer (score 21):

### Updated answer

The `round(someDecimal)` is the old C style. As of Swift 3, doubles and floats have a built in Swift function.

```
var x = 0.8
x.round() // x is 1.0 (rounds x in place)
```

or

```
var x = 0.8
var y = x.rounded() // y is 1.0, x is 0.8
```

See my answer [fuller answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785079/3681880) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785349/3681880)) for more details about how different [rounding rules](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule) can be used.

As other answers have noted, if you want to round to the thousandth, then multiply temporarily by `1000` before you round.

Answer (score 11):

```
func round(value: Float, decimalPlaces: UInt) {
  decimalValue = pow(10, decimalPlaces)
  round(value * decimalValue) / decimalValue
}
…
func round(value: CGFloat, decimalPlaces: UInt)
func round(value: Double, decimalPlaces: UInt)
func roundf(value: Float, decimalPlaces: UInt)
```

Comment: `    static func round_pow_2( value: CGFloat, decimalPlaces: CGFloat ) -> CGFloat {
        let decimalValue = pow( 2.0, decimalPlaces )
        return round( value * decimalValue ) / decimalValue
    }`

Comment: Could be just me but that function doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it. You could easily do this for `Float`, or probably make it generic so it's for any of those.

```
public extension CGFloat {
    func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int = 2) -> CGFloat {
        let multiplier = CGFloat(10^decimals)
        return round(multiplier * self) / multiplier
    }
}
```

Comment: 10^decimal does a bitwise XOR. It should be replaced with pow or powf should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

```
(x/1000).rounded()*1000
```

Comment: This will give 0 if `x` is 0.6849 as given in original question. Should be `(x*1000).rounded()/1000`

Answer (score 3):

This will round to any value not limited by powers of 10.

```
extension Double {
    func roundToNearestValue(value: Double) -> Double {
        let remainder = self % value
        let shouldRoundUp = remainder >= value/2 ? true : false
        let multiple = floor(self / value)
        let returnValue = !shouldRoundUp ? value * multiple : value * multiple + value
        return returnValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a=1.2344 
var b:String = String(format: "%0.2f",a) 
print(b)
```

Output:

```
1.23
```

The output you got is of string type. So, you need to convert into other types if needed. The below link tells you how to convert:

[https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2015/9/28/how-to-convert-strings-into-double-and-float-values-using-swift-2#:~:text=Convert%20Swift%20String%20to%20Double,(Double(%22200.0%22)!)](https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2015/9/28/how-to-convert-strings-into-double-and-float-values-using-swift-2#:%7E:text=Convert%20Swift%20String%20to%20Double,(Double(%22200.0%22)!))

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's documentation for [`round()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884722-round) and [`rounded(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2886735-rounded).