# How to round a Double to the nearest Int in swift?

Tags: swift, int, double, rounding

I'm trying to make a calculator of growth rate (`Double`) that will round the result to the nearest Integer and recalculate from there, as such:

```
let firstUsers = 10.0
let growth = 0.1
var users = firstUsers
var week = 0


while users < 14 {
    println("week \(week) has \(users) users")
    users += users * growth
    week += 1
}
```

but I've been unable so far.

*EDIT*
I kinda did it like so:

```
var firstUsers = 10.0
let growth = 0.1
var users:Int = Int(firstUsers)
var week = 0


while users <= 14 {
    println("week \(week) has \(users) users")
    firstUsers += firstUsers * growth
    users = Int(firstUsers)
    week += 1
}
```

Although I don't mind that it is always rounding down, I don't like it because `firstUsers` had to become a variable and change throughout the program (in order to make the next calculation), which I don't want it to happen.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

There is a `round` available in the `Foundation` library *(it's actually in `Darwin`, but `Foundation` imports `Darwin` and most of the time you'll want to use `Foundation` instead of using `Darwin` directly)*.

```
import Foundation

users = round(users)
```

Running your code in a playground and then calling:

```
print(round(users))
```

Outputs:

> 15.0

`round()` always rounds up when the decimal place is `>= .5` and down when it's `< .5` (standard rounding). You can use `floor()` to force rounding down, and `ceil()` to force rounding up.

If you need to round to a specific place, then you multiply by `pow(10.0, number of places)`, `round`, and then divide by `pow(10, number of places)`:

Round to 2 decimal places:

```
let numberOfPlaces = 2.0
let multiplier = pow(10.0, numberOfPlaces)
let num = 10.12345
let rounded = round(num * multiplier) / multiplier
print(rounded)
```

Outputs:

> 10.12

***Note:** Due to the way floating point math works, `rounded` may not always be perfectly accurate. It's best to think of it more of an approximation of rounding. If you're doing this for display purposes, it's better to use string formatting to format the number rather than using math to round it.*

Comment: Hmm ```pow()``` unfortunately not available in a playground

Comment: @MrBr, `pow()` is defined in the Darwin library, so you need to `import Darwin` first (or `import Foundation` or `import Cocoa` or `import UIKit`, all of which end up importing Darwin internally).

Comment: There is also `lround()` which returns an `Int`.

Comment: "`round()` always rounds up when the decimal place is >= .5 and down when it's < .5 (standard rounding)." Except when it doesn't. `round(-16.5)` returns -17, not -16. Is this a bug?

Comment: @DanielT. - not a bug. It's rounding up to the nearest larger negative number. 
Think about it this way, +16.5 to +17 is moving 0.5 further away from zero. That means -16.5 to -17 is also 0.5 further away from zero.

Ceil would be the opposite, +16.5 to +16 is 0.5 closer to zero and -16.5 to -16 is also 0.5 closer to zero

Answer (score 169):

To round a double to the nearest integer, just use [`round()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/2297801-round).

```
var x = 3.7
x.round() // x = 4.0
```

If you don't want to modify the original value, then use [`rounded()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/2297073-rounded):

```
let x = 3.7
let y = x.rounded() // y = 4.0. x = 3.7
```

As one might expect ([or might not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking)), a number like `3.5` is rounded up and a number like `-3.5` is rounded down. If you need different rounding behavior than that, you can use one of the [rounding rules](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule). For example:

```
var x = 3.7
x.round(.towardZero) // 3.0
```

If you need an actual `Int` then just cast it to one (but only if you are certain that the Double won't be greater than `Int.max`):

```
let myInt = Int(myDouble.rounded())
```

#### Notes

- This answer is completely rewritten. My old answer dealt with the C math functions like `round`, `lround`, `floor`, and `ceil`. However, now that Swift has this functionality built in, I can no longer recommend using those functions. Thanks to @dfri for pointing this out to me. Check out [@dfri's excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488326/3681880). I also did something similar for [rounding a `CGFloat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785079/3681880).

Comment: Int(myDouble.rounded())   <--- this might actually throw an exception if the double doesn't fit the Int

Comment: @Toad, are you sure? I don't see that in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1538869-init).

Comment: I just solved a crash in production with this exact issue. But even if I was wrong and it wouldn't crash, then still it would still give unexpected results for doubles > maxint

Comment: @Toad, right, good point, thanks. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: lround() kind of feels nicer than Int(myDouble.rounded())

Answer (score 135):

## Swift 3 & 4 - making use of the `rounded(_:)` method as blueprinted in the `FloatingPoint` protocol

The [`FloatingPoint` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint) (to which e.g. `Double` and `Float` conforms) blueprints the [`rounded(_:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/2297073-rounded)

> ```
> func rounded(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) -> Self
> ```

Where [`FloatingPointRoundingRule`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpointroundingrule) is an enum enumerating a number of different rounding rules:

> **`case awayFromZero`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is greater than or
>   equal to that of the source.
>
> **`case down`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value that is less than or equal to the
>   source.
>
> **`case toNearestOrAwayFromZero`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value; if two values are equally close,
>   the one with greater magnitude is chosen.
>
> **`case toNearestOrEven`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value; if two values are equally close,
>   the even one is chosen.
>
> **`case towardZero`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is less than or
>   equal to that of the source.
>
> **`case up`**
>
> Round to the closest allowed value that is greater than or equal to
>   the source.

We make use of similar examples to the ones from [@Suragch's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785349/4573247) to show these different rounding options in practice.

## `.awayFromZero`

Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is greater than or equal to that of the source; no direct equivalent among the C functions, as this uses, conditionally on sign of `self`, `ceil` or `floor`, for positive and negative values of `self`, respectively.

```
3.000.rounded(.awayFromZero) // 3.0
3.001.rounded(.awayFromZero) // 4.0
3.999.rounded(.awayFromZero) // 4.0

(-3.000).rounded(.awayFromZero) // -3.0
(-3.001).rounded(.awayFromZero) // -4.0
(-3.999).rounded(.awayFromZero) // -4.0
```

## `.down`

Equivalent to the C `floor` function.

```
3.000.rounded(.down) // 3.0
3.001.rounded(.down) // 3.0
3.999.rounded(.down) // 3.0

(-3.000).rounded(.down) // -3.0
(-3.001).rounded(.down) // -4.0
(-3.999).rounded(.down) // -4.0
```

## `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero`

Equivalent to the C `round` function.

```
3.000.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // 3.0
3.001.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // 3.0
3.499.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // 3.0
3.500.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // 4.0
3.999.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // 4.0

(-3.000).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // -3.0
(-3.001).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // -3.0
(-3.499).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // -3.0
(-3.500).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // -4.0
(-3.999).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) // -4.0
```

This rounding rule can also be accessed using the zero argument [`rounded()` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/2295900-rounded).

```
3.000.rounded() // 3.0
// ...

(-3.000).rounded() // -3.0
// ...
```

## `.toNearestOrEven`

Round to the closest allowed value; if two values are equally close, the even one is chosen; equivalent to the C `rint` (/very similar to `nearbyint`) function.

```
3.499.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 3.0
3.500.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 4.0 (up to even)
3.501.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 4.0

4.499.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 4.0
4.500.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 4.0 (down to even)
4.501.rounded(.toNearestOrEven) // 5.0 (up to nearest)
```

## `.towardZero`

Equivalent to the C `trunc` function.

```
3.000.rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0
3.001.rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0
3.999.rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0

(-3.000).rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0
(-3.001).rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0
(-3.999).rounded(.towardZero) // 3.0
```

If the purpose of the rounding is to prepare to work with an integer (e.g. using `Int` by `FloatPoint` initialization after rounding), we might simply make use of the fact that when initializing an `Int` using a `Double` (or `Float` etc), the decimal part will be truncated away.

```
Int(3.000) // 3
Int(3.001) // 3
Int(3.999) // 3

Int(-3.000) // -3
Int(-3.001) // -3
Int(-3.999) // -3
```

## `.up`

Equivalent to the C `ceil` function.

```
3.000.rounded(.up) // 3.0
3.001.rounded(.up) // 4.0
3.999.rounded(.up) // 4.0

(-3.000).rounded(.up) // 3.0
(-3.001).rounded(.up) // 3.0
(-3.999).rounded(.up) // 3.0
```

---

#### Addendum: visiting the source code for `FloatingPoint` to verify the C functions equivalence to the different `FloatingPointRoundingRule` rules

If we'd like, we can take a look at the source code for `FloatingPoint` protocol to directly see the C function equivalents to the public `FloatingPointRoundingRule` rules.

From [swift/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/720f496b2e6f23de8005edbcb598394851b03a58/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb#L1718) we see that the default implementation of the `rounded(_:)` method makes us of the mutating `round(_:)` method:

> ```
> public func rounded(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) -> Self {
>     var lhs = self
>     lhs.round(rule)
>     return lhs
> }
> ```

From [swift/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/720f496b2e6f23de8005edbcb598394851b03a58/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L529) we find the default implementation of `round(_:)`, in which the equivalence between the `FloatingPointRoundingRule` rules and the C rounding functions is apparent:

> ```
> public mutating func round(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) {
>     switch rule {
>     case .toNearestOrAwayFromZero:
>         _value = Builtin.int_round_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>     case .toNearestOrEven:
>         _value = Builtin.int_rint_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>     case .towardZero:
>         _value = Builtin.int_trunc_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>     case .awayFromZero:
>         if sign == .minus {
>             _value = Builtin.int_floor_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>         }
>         else {
>             _value = Builtin.int_ceil_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>         }
>     case .up:
>         _value = Builtin.int_ceil_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>     case .down:
>         _value = Builtin.int_floor_FPIEEE${bits}(_value)
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @iosMentalist thanks for the prompt, I've update the title of answer.

Comment: If I want any equation like, 3.0 = 3, 3.1 = 3.5, 3.4 = 3.5, 3.6 = 4, 3.9 - 4

Answer (score 7):

```
**In Swift**

var a = 14.123456789
var b = 14.123456789
var c = 14.123456789
var d = 14.123456789
var e = 14.123456789
var f = 14.123456789

a.rounded(.up)                      //15
b.rounded(.down)                    //14
c.rounded(.awayFromZero)            //15
d.rounded(.towardZero)              //14
e.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) //14
f.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)         //14
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also extend FloatingPoint in Swift 3 as follow:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func rounded(to n: Int) -> Self {
        let n = Self(n)
        return (self / n).rounded() * n

    }
}

324.0.rounded(to: 5)   // 325
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? What's `Self` means?

Comment: @Jacky Self refers to the class FloatingPoint whereas self refers to the instance of that class.

Comment: @GeorgeYacoub Self refers to the type that conforms to FloatingPoint that’s being extended (in that sample usage is a Double) but they are structures, not classes

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3:
If you want to round to a certain digit number e.g. 5.678434 -> 5.68 you can just combine the round() or roundf() function with a multiplication:

```
let value:Float = 5.678434
let roundedValue = roundf(value * 100) / 100
print(roundedValue) //5.68
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3

```
var myNum = 8.09
myNum.rounded() // result = 8 and leaves myNum unmodified
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about this one before. One note: `myNum.rounded()` does not change `myNum`, but `myNum.round()` does.

Comment: @Suragch, I've edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score -1):

A very easy solution worked for me:

```
  if (62 % 50 != 0) {
      var number = 62 / 50 + 1 // adding 1 is doing the actual "round up"
  }
```

*number* contains value 2

Comment: Use `floatValue.rounded()` default function.

Comment: This isn't really addressing the question at all since there is no usage of floating point numbers of any variety, all calculations are done using `Int`.  It will also yield incorrect values for many cases depending on your expectation of "round" (i.e., 62.0/50.0 rounded should be 1.0). This is closest to "ceiling", ie., the next integral value greater than given value.  But even that isn't correct as the ceiling of 50.0/50.0 is 1.0, but your method will yield 2.0.

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way I came across

```
let weightValue = 143.69
print("Rounded off weight value = \(Int(weightValue))")
```

Alternate method:

```
print("Rounded off weight value = \((String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)))")
```