# Timer Not Stopping When Supposed To Swift 2

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have coded my timer with the idea in mind that when my timer reaches 10, it stops. But for some reason, it doesn't.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SinglePlayer: UIViewController {
    var timerCount = 0.0
    @IBOutlet weak var timer: UILabel!
    var timerVar = NSTimer()

    func isCounting() {
        timerCount += 0.1
        timer.text = "\(timerCount)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if timerCount <= 10.0{
            timerVar = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "isCounting", userInfo: nil, repeats:true)
        } else {
            timerVar.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the solution to put the condition check into the `isCounting()` function I suspect that you will never see the full incrementing of the timer when the timer is started that soon in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put condition in the callback function and not on `viewDidLoad` which is only called once on the load.

```
func isCounting() {
    timerCount += 0.1
    timer.text = "\(timerCount)"

    if timerCount >= 10.0 {
        timerVar.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx so much i really appreciate it worked right away

Comment: no prob, when you find solution to your question, you mark it as accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: and u know how to make the .99999999 go away?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350977/how-to-round-a-double-to-the-nearest-int-in-swift