# Rounding half to even

Tags: ios, swift

What's the formula for Banker's rounding in Swift language?

For example: 134.5675 becomes 134 and 135.5345 becomes 136

Thus far I've tried something like this:

```
extension Double {
    func roundHalfToEven() -> Double {
        return round(self * 100) / 100
    }
}
```

But it's nowhere near returns what I need.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350977/how-to-round-a-double-to-the-nearest-int-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove multiplying and dividing by 100. Then use `lrint` (instead of `round`), which rounds the input to the nearest integer.

Comment: Bankers rounding is supposed to be "round half even" which is not the same as round to the nearest integer

Comment: @aeropapa17 maybe there was something confusing in the way I put it, but the fact is that `lrint` returns the nearest integer according to the current rounding mode, which is by default the nearest integer (FE_TONEAREST), which is actually "nearest even", AKA "banker's rounding":
lrint(1.5) = 2, lrint(2.5) = 2, lrint(3.234) = 3, lrint(3.5) = 4, lrint(4.6) = 5

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for clarifying.