# What is the swift code to apply Round Up or Down Sum Amount?

Tags: swift, decimal

I try on Xcode - Playground.

This is my code. Beginner.

========
    import UIKit

```
var num1 : Double = 0.055  // Stock Price
var num2 : Double = 18     // Lots
var num3 : Double = 1000   // Share Per Lots

var sum1 : Double = num1 * num2 * num3    // Gross Share Price

var sum5 : Double = sum1 * (0.03/100) // Clearing Charges  // Answer Playground Return is " 0.297 "
```

My Questions is the "sum5" I want answer round up and display " 0.30 "

It is possible in swift code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it this way:

```
var roundOfSum5 : Double = Double(round(100 * sum5)/100)  //0.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lots for the help in swift. It worked. Thank Dharmesh Kheni.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351144/5327882)

If you need to round to a specific place, then you multply by `pow(10.0, numberOfPlaces)`, `round`, and then divide by `pow(10, numberOfPlaces)`. In your case the number of places is `2.0`:

```
let numberOfPlaces = 2.0
let multiplier = pow(10.0, numberOfPlaces)
let rounded = round(sum5 * multiplier) / multiplier
print(rounded) // 0.3
```

If you have a number like `sum5 = 0.3465` and you want to round to the third place after the decimal you can use `3.0` for numberOfPlaces and get as result `0.347`