# How to round double in swift to 2 places with math round

Tags: swift

The standard swift's round() function just cuts off everything and leaves 1 place after the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension Double {
    // Rounds the double to decimal places value
    // Usage: (doubleVar).roundToPlaces(x) 
    // Where x is the number of places
    func roundToPlaces(places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return round(self * divisor) / divisor
    }
}
```

Source: [Rounding a double value to x number of decimal places in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)