# How to get a Double value up to 2 Decimal places

Tags: swift, number-formatting

In my app I am dealing with currency which is need to upto two decimal digit ,  I have used number formatter for this to display up to two decimal place but When I want this double value up like 0.7 to 0.70 , I am unable to to do that , type double is always giving me 0.7 but i want 0.7 to 0.70

Comment: You want a func that convert a double value to a string with the formatted value? What did you try?

Comment: I want a double upto 2 decimal places

Comment: @Uma_Shanker_Tiwari Strings contain formatting information, doubles don't – therefore you cannot add trailing zeros to their value. If you simply want to round a double to a set number of decimal places, then [see this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
let pi = 3.14159

let text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [pi])

print(text) // output = 3.14
```

Comment: `let val = 1.2345`
`let nVal = Double(round(100*val)/100)`
`print(nVal)`

Answer (score 10):

You should use `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let pi = 3.14159
let str = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(pi)!

print(str)
```

Comment: My need was specific for number formatter..thanks..!!