# Simple calculation in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift2

Just trying my first simple attempt on a calculation in swift2, but I can't seem to get it right. 
I have a UITextField input called ValueA
I want to du the following calculation on that input (i can have decimals)
`(((ValueA * ValueA)+3)*1.36)`
The result must return a number with up to two decimals.
I have tried the following:

```
let kw = 1.36
let three: Double = 3
var a: Double = NSString(string: ValueA.text!).doubleValue
var b: Double = NSString(string: ValueB.text!).doubleValue
var answer:Double = (((a * a) + three) * kw)
let answerFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
answerFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
answerFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let Ranswer = answerFormatter.stringFromNumber(answer)!
Result.text = Ranswer`
```

It kindda works, but sometimes my simulator crashes and sometimes it gets me the right answer but with more decimals as zeroes eg: 45.23000000 (instead of 45.23)

Can someone clean up my code? The answer need to go back into a textfield. Remember I am a total newbee in swift :)

Comment: What is the stacktrace you get from the simulator crash? Could you post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that the always enter a valid number into `ValueA` and `ValueB`. That's one possible source for the crash. Better check that the text can be converted to numbers.

Try this (not tested):

```
let kw = 1.36
let three = 3.0

if let a = Double(ValueA.text!), b = Double(ValueB.text!) {
    let answer = (((a * a) + three) * kw)

    let answerFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    answerFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    answerFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    let Ranswer = answerFormatter.stringFromNumber(answer)!
    Result.text = Ranswer
} else {
    print("You must enter a number into ValueA and ValueB")
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect. I had made the UITextfields as show numeric keyboard, så that is why I didn't check for numerics values.
Where does the Print go? I can't see it anywhere in the simulator?
Is there anyway to use comma in this calculation? eg 5,5 instead of 5.5? When I use comma nothing happens

Comment: I think `Double` uses the default separator for your locale when converting string to number. Use `NSNumberFormatter` if you want to customize that. `print` will go to the Debug Console. Press `Cmd + Shift + Y` to open it

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
let kw = 1.36
let three: Double = 3
var a = Double(ValueA.text!)!
var b = Double(ValueB.text!)!
var answer = (((a * a) + three) * kw)


 let Ranswer = String(format:"%.2f", answer)
Result.text = Ranswer
```

And are you sure you wanna do `a * a`? and not `a * b`. Just making sure, because you arent using b anywhere

you can also use

```
let Ranswer = Double(round(100 * answer)/100)
Result.text = String(Ranswer)
```

Source of information : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

Comment: Multiplying and dividing by 100 is no appropriate method to format a floating point number. Formatting with some format specifier is. :)

Comment: @Eiko I'm with you on this! I'm not the original one to answer this. But I included this because I absolutely love the creativity of the guy who came up with this method (credits to him through the link) I have changed the answer though, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Can't make it work. Build fails. It should be a*a. 
I have not made the code where b is used, yet :)

Comment: Why would the build fail? share the error? and also the code that you tried