# How to round the double to decimal places value in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following method that's working fine with Swift 2:

```
func roundToPlaces(_ places:Int) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return round(self * divisor) / divisor
}
```

But it's not working with Swift 3. Someone please tell me its replacement in Swift 3.

Comment: What is self here?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift

Comment: thanks for trying to help