# Swift array of dictionaries contains a double, saving to user defaults adding decimal places

Tags: arrays, swift, double

I create an array called testArray.  I then save it to user defaults.  And retrieve it from user defaults.  When I log the original "testArray" and log the retrieved "retrieveArray", the longitude and latitude fields have changed.

For example:

**testArray: "longitude": 31.132013199999999**

**retrievedArray: "longitude": 31.1320132**

Why is this?  And stranger still - why is the retrieved array logging correctly, but the original array is getting logged with extra decimal places?

Thank you.

```
let testarray =
Array(
arrayLiteral:
["longitude":31.1320132],
["longitude":31.1320132],
["longitude":31.1320132],
["longitude":31.1320132])

UserDefaults.standard.set(testarray, forKey: "myTestArray")

let retrievedArray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"myTestArray")

NSLog((testarray as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>)[2].description)

NSLog((retrievedArray as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>)[2].description)
```

OUTPUT

```
app[75897:9783167] ["longitude": 31.132013199999999]

app[75897:9783167] ["longitude": 31.1320132]
```

UPDATE: Some have said that "duplicate question" is used too aggressively on StackOverflow, and I have noticed that at times. But in this case, yes!  This "duplicate question" does seem to speak to the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

I suggest that you convert the double to string, or round the value. You can see many solutions [where](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036978/3440266).

Comment: Thank you Macabeus. How does the rounding enter the picture?  In the examples in the "where" link you provided, they all explicitly contain a direct reference to rounding.  In the code I have posted, there is no call to a rounding function or property.  Are you saying the rounding is being done automatically?  What seems confusing is that if this is a rounding error, it is happening on a literal value which I declare and then output to the console without rounding it. Thanks!