# iOS Swift: How to return the largest value in a key-value multi-dimensional array?

Tags: ios, arrays

Let me explain, let's say I have this array:

```
var dateDouble_ARRAY = [Date : [Double] ]()

dateDouble_ARRAY = [2017-08-06 07:00:00 +0000: [11.880000000000001, 3.0], 
    2017-08-08 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2017-08-01 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2017-08-09 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2017-08-02 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2017-08-03 07:00:00 +0000: [6.5499999999999998], 
    2017-08-10 07:00:00 +0000: [2.0] ]
```

Each `Date` key has a value that could consist of multiple `Double` numbers.

What I would like to find out is how can I find the largest value in this array?

For example, in this case, the largest value is `11.880000000000001 + 3.0` = **14.88** (rounded) because the key-value pair consists of 2 `Double` values, and **14.88** is larger then any other key-value pair.

However, if the array consisted of:

```
dateDouble_ARRAY = [2017-08-06 07:00:00 +0000: [3.0], 
    2017-08-08 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2017-08-01 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2017-08-09 07:00:00 +0000: [6.0], 
    2017-08-02 07:00:00 +0000: [5.0], 
    2017-08-03 07:00:00 +0000: [6.5499999999999998], 
    2017-08-10 07:00:00 +0000: [2.0] ]
```

Then the largest value would be **6.55** (rounded).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
let maxValue = dateDouble_ARRAY.values.map({$0.reduce(0,+)}).max()
```

if you want to round then

```
let maxValue = dateDouble_ARRAY.values.map({yourRoundMethod($0.reduce(0,+))}).max()
```

**tested**

***Input***

> [2016-02-02 08:00:00 +0000: [2], 2016-05-01 08:00:00 +0000: [5, 6], 2016-03-02 08:00:00 +0000: [3, 4], 2016-01-02 08:00:00 +0000: [0, 1]]

***Result***

> 11

Hope this helps

Comment: can you give me an example of what the `yourRoundMethod` would be?

Comment: there are many ways to round so I suggest read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift and use what you want, `yourRoundMethod` will be the round method you decide

Comment: saved me again!

Comment: @Pangu I am glad to help you, happy coding, and best regards

Answer (score 0):

[reduce](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) and then reduce some more

```
 let value = dateDouble_ARRAY.values.reduce(0){max($0, $1.reduce(0,+))}
 print(value)
```