# Round a digit upto two decimal place in Swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm getting a value of digits which i'm trying to convert to two decimal places. But when i convert it it makes the result to 0.00 . The digits are this `0.24612035420731018` . When get its .2f value it shows 0.00. The code that i tried is this,

```
 let  digit = FindResturantSerivce.instance.FindResModelInstance[indexPath.row].distance
    let text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [digit])
    print(text)
```

Comment: how about using a [number-formatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) and try to play with the [significant-digits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1417793-usessignificantdigits) property?

Comment: i haven't tried it. @holex

Comment: I'd recommend to use it, it is a way more elegant and much easier and cleaner solution than the answer with the manual patching you have accepted eventually :)

Comment: @Hamza check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172525/get-string-from-float-without-rounding-its-value/49172767#49172767 may this will help you in some way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a format string to round up to two decimal places and convert the double to a String:

```
let currentRatio = Double (rxCurrentTextField.text!)! / Double (txCurrentTextField.text!)!
railRatioLabelField.text! = String(format: "%.2f", currentRatio)
```

Example:

```
let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = Double(String(format: "%.2f", myDouble)) // 3.14

let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", myDouble) // "3.14"
```

If you want to round up your last decimal place, you could do something like this :

```
let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = Double(String(format: "%.2f", ceil(myDouble*100)/100)) // 3.15

let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(myDouble*100)/100) // "3.15"
```

Comment: Bro its showing me this error, Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int' . @Md Rashed Pervez

Comment: i'm getting value of digits in a string formart. @ Md Rashed Pervez

Comment: I believe those examples can help you to solve your issue. Try them with your digits. Hope this will solve your problem @Hamza

Comment: yup got that. i have converted it to Double. thanks a lot bro. @Md Rashed Pervez

Answer (score 35):

If you want to really round the number, and not just format it as rounded for display purposes, then I prefer something a little more general-purpose:

```
extension Double {
    func rounded(digits: Int) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10.0, Double(digits))
        return (self * multiplier).rounded() / multiplier
    }
}
```

So you can then do something like:

```
let foo = 3.14159.rounded(digits: 3) // 3.142
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because **Double(String(format: "%.2f", myDouble))**  is not working for me in cclocation latitude longitude case.