# Get string from float without rounding its value

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point

I am facing one scenario where I need only 2 places after the decimal point of float without rounding its actual value.

I tried following lines of code :

```
extension Float {

func stringWith2Decimals() -> String {
    return String(format: "%.2f", self)
  }
}
```

This gives me following output:

```
var floatValue = 10.99999999
```

> Output: 11.00
>
> Expected result: 10.99

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: See this-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014054/round-a-digit-upto-two-decimal-place-in-swift/49014278#49014278

Comment: You need a formatter for it. I have added an answer to this post. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you, I have tested it.

```
let floatValue = 10.99999999
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .down
let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue))
print(s)
```

Updated answer for ***one more case is there for value 10.9 it should show 10.90.***

**Case 1:** When you only want to print actual decimal digits or max 2 decimal digit

```
 let floatValue = 10.999999
    let floatValue1 = 10
    let floatValue2 = 10.9
    let floatValue3 = 10.91


    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.roundingMode = .down
    let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue))
    print(s!)  // 10.99
    let s1 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue1))
    print(s1!)  // 10
    let s2 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue2))
    print(s2!)  // 10.9
    let s3 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue3))
    print(s3!)  // 10.91
```

**Case 2:** When you always want to print two decimal digits.

```
 let floatValue = 10.999999
    let floatValue1 = 10
    let floatValue2 = 10.9
    let floatValue3 = 10.91


    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.roundingMode = .down
    let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue))
    print(s!) // 10.99
    let s1 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue1))
    print(s1!) // 10.00
    let s2 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue2))
    print(s2!) // 10.90
    let s3 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatValue3))
    print(s3!) // 10.91
```

Hope you get what you want. if yes then please vote up else let me know what is your actual requirement.

Updated answer for an issue . ***for value like 10.9999999999999999 its printing 11.00, Not 10.99.***

```
  let floatValue3 = 10.99999999999999
    let (wholePart, fractionalPart) = modf(floatValue3)
    let stringFractionalPart = "\(fractionalPart)"
    let stringWholePart = "\(Int(wholePart))"

    let aryFractionalPart = stringFractionalPart.components(separatedBy: ".")

    var valueToDisplay = stringWholePart

    if aryFractionalPart.count >= 2 {
        let decimalDigits = aryFractionalPart[1]
        let digit2 = decimalDigits.prefix(2)
        valueToDisplay = "\(valueToDisplay).\(digit2)"
    }

    print(valueToDisplay)
```

Hope now I fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh one more case is there for value 10.9 it should show 10.90. what is the correct approach to do it?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger please check the answer I have updated it. more or less you have to play with  max/min FractionDigits

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh will try and let you know.

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh for value like 10.9999999999999999 its printing 11.00, Not 10.99. I don't want any kind of rounding in it. it seems that formatter is rounding value.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I have tried with a different approach but not able to get the desired result. Sometimes we can't use provided methods we have to make a trick to get the desired result. Can you please let me know what is the actual scenario of requiring these values, from where you get the decimal value and in what form. then I can make some sort of workaround for you.

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh I am actually building payment app in which I am getting these long float values from the server. since it is payment app I don't want to show the user long values I just want to cut it to  2 places after decimal point without rounding its original value.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh The workaround for the problem is good but for first case 10.9 should show 10.90 it doesn't really work. But nice try. Thanks for your efforts. I have solved this issue with some changes from backend so that now backend will not send such long float values. The client will only do the work of showing the value. I have upvoted your answer.