# Is there a way to override Double to make it every double value 2 decimal place by default in swift?

Tags: swift, double, overriding, decimal

I'm writing an application in swift 4 and I do not want to round my double  value every time I create a double. By default, I wish to make it 2 decimal place.

The double values will be all for currency display/saving purposes

E.g. USD 10.00, instead, it is saving like: 10.0

I'm searching for something to override the Double function.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: There's no need to round every double. Just use a proper `NumberFormatter` whenever you needs to show a double to a user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a double value to x number of decimal places in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

Comment: Are you using these two decimal place numbers to represent currency values?

Comment: @CRD, yes exactly. Its an application related to currency only. So, instead of handing the rounding function every time, I wish to be able to do it by default.

Comment: @Smartcat, I saw this post before and that's not what I was looking for, unfortunately

Comment: @JeffYeungSamWai I've updated my answer according to your needs. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: That's just not how `Double` works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @JeffYeungSamWai In essence, double doesn't store "digits" (decimal digits, to be clear), in the sense of the way you and I think of decimals. It stores fractional parts as some sum of `1/2`, `1/4`, `1/8`, `1/16`, ... `1/(2^56)`. For example, `1.825` gets encoded as `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8`. Any numbers that aren't precises expressible as a sum of powers of 2, are rounded off to the nearest available number that can.

Comment: @Alexander. Yeps, Thank you for the information and I understand what you are trying to say, but it doesn't help me in what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JeffYeungSamWai I guess it's just trying to say "you can't do, what you're trying to do". Instead, us a CurrencyFormatter to convert your double to string, enforcing that it only prints 2 digits, and whatever other requirements you have

Comment: @Alexander, Yes! I have decided to go with the currencyFormatter, I have created a static function for which I call it everywhere and whenever I need it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

> Its an application related to currency only. So, instead of handing the rounding function every time, I wish to be able to do it by default.

It is best to avoid `Float` & `Double` for currency applications. These types are based on *binary* floating point and are not precise with *decimal* fractions.

> E.g. take 34 cents/pence/whatever in a currency where 100 of these make the dollar/pound/whatever then in you might use the decimal 0.34 to represent this, or 3/10 + 4/100 as the sum of 1/(10^n) fractions. Now binary floating-point (and fixed-point) uses sums of 1/(2^n) fractions. So 34/100 = 1/4 (25/100) + 9/100 = 1/4 + 1/16 + 275/10000 = 1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 + ... (this sum could be finite or infinite depending on the decimal fraction)

Note that given this binary base your requirement to have two *decimal* places is not strictly possible, as regardless of how many *binary* places you limit yourself to some of your decimal factions will be imprecise.

So what is the solution? Integers (or fixed-point numbers, see below).

If you only need to support decimal currencies, i.e. those where the small unit is 1/100 of the larger one as in dollars/cents, pounds/pence) then you can simply use large enough integers and keep your amounts in the small unit. E.g store $12.34 as 1234 cents. If you need greater precision (say you're doing share prices etc.) you might store your values as some (decimal) factions of the small unit, say 1/100 of a cent. In this way all calculations use precise integer arithmetic operations. For string conversions you need to add/remove the currency point and then do integer conversions, or use remainder/division to split your stored value into its components and format each one.

If you need to support non-decimal currencies, or you need more range than storing as (some fraction of) the smaller unit will allow in your largest integer type, then you can store the large & small units as two integer values and handle carry operations between them yourself.

You can wrap the operations up as a value (`struct`) type in Swift.

Some language support *decimal fixed point* arithmetic, or provide libraries which do, which is similar to what we've just described; there might be a library for Swift out there if you look. (See for example Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), that link also covers the points explained above.)

If you wish to stick with available types then look at using `Decimal` which is a *decimal floating point* type which provides 38 decimal digits of precision. It is not designed specifically for currency but you can use `NSDecimalRound` to keep numbers to the required number of decimal places (and it even supports bankers rounding); to address your specific requirement to do this automatically you would have to wrap/extend and implement your own operators which combined the standard ones with rounding to the required number of places.

Hope this helps more than it confuses!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try them

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions to your question. But I'm not sure if they'll satisfy your needs. First is overriding `didSet` of your `Double` currency value variable like this:

```
var currencyValue: Double = 0.0 {
   didSet {
        // Do the rounding
        let divisor = pow(10.0, 2) // 2 is the place number

        currencyValue = (currencyValue * divisor).rounded() / divisor
   }
}
```

Second is using `extensions` to create a new `init` function for `Double` which does the rounding immediately.

```
extension Double {

    init(value: Double, roundTo places: Double) {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, places)

        self = (value * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
// Use the extension initialization
Double(value: 10.22, roundTo: 2)
```

Although these can be used as solutions I must agree with [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy). Using `NumberFormatter` would allow you to format currencies much easily and locally. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

So to achieve what you are actually looking for we need to do some little adjustments. I'll update override method:

```
var currencyValue: String = "0.00" {
   get {
        // Convert String value to Double
        let doubleValue = Double(currencyValue)

        // Do the rounding
        let divisor = pow(10.0, 2) // 2 is the place number

        doubleValue = (doubleValue * divisor).rounded() / divisor

        // Format the number
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 // We want at least 2 decimal places
        if let formattedString = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(doubleValue)) {
             return formattedString
        }

        return currencyValue
   }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var double = 10.2
currencyValue = "\(double)" // Setting the double value as String
print(currencyValue) // will print 10.20
```

Comment: OK. I edited my question, to be clearer. Your answer is close to what I'm looking for though, but it still doesn't work for values like USD 10.00

Comment: Anyway, I guess I will listen to you and @rmaddy advice to use NumberFormatter. It is extra work but it works.