# Swift specify double without converting to string

Tags: swift, double

I want to specify my (slider) double to 2 decimals but xcode won't let me do that:

```
return (Double(pris, specifier: "%.2f"))
```

And i don't want to convert it into a string and then format it because numbers like 600000000 are then unreadable.

I have tried solutions like :

```
extension Double {
// Rounds the double to 'places' significant digits
  func roundTo(places:Int) -> Double {
    guard self != 0.0 else {
        return 0
    }
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places) - ceil(log10(fabs(self))))
    return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding a double value to x number of decimal places in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

Comment: Unfortunately no, looked there all day..

Comment: **And i don't want to convert it into a string and then format it because numbers like 600000000 are then unreadable.** 600000000 is an Integer. If you give 600000000.00 then it will work for sure.

Comment: `but xcode won't let me do that` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry if i was unclear, it gives 600000000.0000000 right now

Comment: If that link doesn't help then you need to clarify what you are asking

Comment: I have around 5 sliders (doubles) which then are calculated together for an output. This output gives a lot of decimals.

Comment: As mentioned in Joakim's link/comment, always round first then format & recast to string.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
extension Double {
    func roundedTo(places: Int) -> Double {
        let conversion = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * conversion).rounded() / conversion
    }
}

print(10.125.roundedTo(places: 2)) // prints 10.13
print(10.124.roundedTo(places: 2)) // prints 10.12
```

Comment: Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Comment: sorry no, still 6 decimals

Comment: Correct: `print(1.999.roundedTo(places: 2))`  gives 2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
let b: Double = Double(600000000.376)
let result = Double(round(100*b)/100)
print(result) // prints 600000000.38
```

Comment: Correct: `> let result = Double(round(100*b)/100)` 
result: Double = 600000000.38

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution was to remove the (Double) before the calculation.

return (Double(pris, specifier: "%.2f"))

should be only

pris, specifier: "%.2f")