# How to use number formatter?

Tags: swift

I am having a problem using `NumberFormatter`. I would like for the variable `output` to only contain a certain amount of digits.

E.g. *3.14* instead of *3.14567899*

I am am getting an error `Ambiguous reference to member 'string(from:)'`:

```
func calculateLength() {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    print(startingLength)
    print(endingLength)
    if startingLength == "Feet" && endingLength == "Inches" {
        output = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(lengthTextFieldValue) * 12) // This is where I am getting the error
        print(output)

        lengthOutputLabel.text = ("\(lengthTextFieldValue) ft = \(output) inches")
    }    
}
```

What is the proper way?

Comment: Double string initializer returns an optional. You need to unwrap it or use the nil coalescing operator. `Double(lengthTextFieldValue) ?? 0` Btw no need to initialize a new NSNumber object. You can use Formatter’s method `string(for: Any)` and pass a Double

Comment: I think you have missed ")" aht the end of code `output = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(lengthTextFieldValue) * 12))`

Comment: @OKMIN I tried that and got an error saying `Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Double'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatter.string()` returns an optional value. 
So you should check `output` is ether nil or non-nil.
`?` after Type(like `String`) means that values is optional. Optional value could has `nil`.

```
func calculateLength() {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2


    print(startingLength)
    print(endingLength)
    if startingLength == "Feet" && endingLength == "Inches" {
        if let output = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(lengthTextFieldValue) * 12)) {
            print(output)
            lengthOutputLabel.text = ("\(lengthTextFieldValue) ft = \(output) inches")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code lies in the line exactly you mentioned:

```
output = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(lengthTextFieldValue)! * 12))
```

The main problem is that the initializer for the `Double` returns an optional value. That you can either mitigate by wrapping the initialization in an `if let` statement, such as:

```
if let myDouble = Double(lengthTextFieldValue) {
    // your code
}
```

Or by using the shorthanded version, given that there is a neutral number you are willing to accept - such as 0 or 1:

```
let myDouble = Double(lengthTextFieldValue) ?? 0
```

What you can also do when you have your `Double` initialized is to round it up to the number of decimal places you want:

```
extension Double {
    func rounded(toPlaces places: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

Comment: I am new to swift how do I add the `extension Double` . Is there anything else to add to it?

Comment: @AmaniH nope, no need, put it in a separate file and you're good to go. You might need to just import Foundation at the top.