# How can use round function without using SwiftUI library for helping Xcode for inferring?

Tags: swift

I was playing around with an extension which I noticed Xcode does not know or it cannot infer `round` and I have to use like `SwiftUI.round` for helping Xcode! why it is the case? I think I do not have to use `SwiftUI.` because round function is a public function. So what happens there? and how can I use just `round` instead of `SwiftUI.round`?

***Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .onAppear {
                let value: Double = 2.69
                print(value.string)
            }
        
    }
}

extension Double {
    var string: String {
        let value: Self = SwiftUI.round(self*10.0)/10.0
        return String(describing: value)
    }
}
```

The issue is here that the round function is public as Xcode say:

```
public func round(_: Double) -> Double
```

So if I create a custom function called:

```
public func test(_ value: Double) -> String {
    return String(describing: value)
}
```

I would be able to call test function just with `test(...)` so why this is not possible with other public function called `round(_: Double)`

Comment: `(self*10.0).rounded()/10.0`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036978/1187415

Comment: Thanks, I want to know why Xcode cannot infer it, I do not have issue for rounding. Because when I import SwiftUI, it must be accessible inside extension as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double` has the [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/round(_:))

```
mutating func round(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule)
```

therefore, inside an extension of that type, `round()` without explicit module name is inferred as this mutating method. As an example, this would compile:

```
extension Double {
    var string: String {
        var x = self * 10.0
        x.round()
        let value = x/10.0
        return String(describing: value)
    }
}
```

You can use `Darwin.round()` or (apparently) `SwiftUI.round()` to refer explicitly to the C library function.

Alternatively, use the `rounded()` method.

Comment: I am not talking about how I can round a value, this is not the question, also I am not talking to `.round()` or `FloatingPointRoundingRule` I am talking about `public func round(_: Double) -> Double` and why the public function is not accessible in extension. I do not need codes, I need explaining about the issue.

Comment: @ioscoder: And I tried to explain it. There is a global `round()` function and a `Double.round()` method. Inside an extension of the Double type, the compiler infers “round” as the `Double.round()` method, and the global function is only accessible with explicit module name..

Comment: Oh, I can see now! So Xcode infer the things it thinks it is the correct one, because we are inside Double extension, but in the fact it ignores the public function we are trying to use, right?

Comment: @ioscoder: Inside a Double extension, “round” is always interpreted as the `Double.round()` method, and not as the global function. – A similar example: Inside an Array extension, “min” is understood as the `Array.min()` method and not as the global `min()` function. That has been treated elsewhere on this site, I think. – That's just how it is. The compiler *could* do better, but it has not been implemented.