# Convert string to number using NumberFormatter not returning expected number

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let sample1 = formatter.number(from: "29.99") ---> 29.99
let sample2 = formatter.number(from: "79.99") ---> 79.98999999999999
```

But I expect to get `79.99` as the result of sample2

Tried using different rounding modes with no help

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because a `Floating Point Number`. You can see what is FPN in [here](https://stevenpcurtis.medium.com/what-is-a-floating-point-number-6991f2f85a28)

If you need 2 decimal value with round , you can use this extension [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32581409/9110909)

```
extension NSNumber {
    func rounded(to decimalPlaces: Int) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10, Double(decimalPlaces))

    return (Double(truncating: self) * multiplier).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) / multiplier
    }
}

  let sample1 = formatter.number(from: "29.99")?.rounded(to: 2) --> will be Optional(29.99)
  let sample2 = formatter.number(from: "79.99")?.rounded(to: 2) --> will be Optional(79.99)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to help with my problem