# How can I extend RealmOptional to add a function on Float in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm

I want to add a `round` method with the specific rounding digits to my `RealmOptional` class. If you want to add the method to your `CGFloat` class, you can write the following (I borrow it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513357/rounding-in-swift-with-round)):

```
public extension CGFloat {
  func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int = 2) -> CGFloat {
        let multiplier = CGFloat(10^decimals)
        return round(multiplier * self) / multiplier
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add this functionality to the `RealmOptional` class, where only type defined as `Float` must be added the method to.

I can't get how it shall be implemented, but the following spit out the error:

> Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type 'Float'

```
import RealmSwift
extension RealmOptional where T: Float {
    func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int = 2) -> CGFloat {
        let multiplier = CGFloat(10^decimals)
        return round(multiplier * self.value!) / multiplier
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can define a protocol, let the wrapped type implement that and then use the protocol as the generic constraint and delegate to the method implemented on the value, as seen below.

```
import QuartzCore

protocol Roundable {
    func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int) -> CGFloat
}

extension Float : Roundable {
    func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int = 2) -> CGFloat {
        let multiplier = pow(10.0, Float(decimals))
        return round(multiplier * CGFloat(self)) / multiplier
    }
}

extension RealmOptional where T: Roundable {
    func roundToDecimals(decimals: Int = 2) -> CGFloat {
        return self.value!.roundToDecimals(decimals)
    }
}
```

But I'd recommend instead to use `maybeFloat.value!.roundToDecimals(2)` to make the unsafe force-unwrapping clear in the calling code and not hiding it away in the implementation.

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply but I finally got that in Swift `^` is not for the `power` operand!

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry didn't even think about that and just took over what you had there.