# Round a double in Swift

Tags: swift, double, rounding

I am making a calculation to find a value of a double (below)

```
let tipAmt = Double(billAmt! * tipPer)
```

However, I want to take this value and round it up to the closest integer. How would I do that. Is there a round call?

Comment: There is a round call, see this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513357/rounding-in-swift-with-round)

Comment: *"Is there a round call?"* – Try `man round` in a Terminal window!

Answer (score 3):

There is, literally a `round()` method that works on `Double`

```
let billAmt: Double? = 23.75
let tipPer: Double = 0.15

let tipAmt = Double(billAmt! * tipPer)

print("tipAmt: \(tipAmt)") // 3.5625

var rounded = round(tipAmt)
print("rounded to nearest dollar: \(rounded)") // 4

rounded = round(tipAmt * 100) / 100
print("rounded to nearest cent: \(rounded)") // 3.56
```